# How to obtain the result of the xth recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

Given a recursion program that prints the result in each recursion in descending order. The output should be only the result  of the xth recursion (Python). Is there a way to stop it after the xth "loop" and obtain only the last result?

Comment: Please provide an example code with your input and expected/actual output. What have you tried? Where have you failed?

Comment: in principle you can give every recursion level a number and stop at some maximum, but it's hard to say ho without knowing what you want to accomplish and what your current code looks like

Comment: `if recursion_counter == xth: return`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable and use it as a counter. When you hit the xth number you can break the recursive and take what you want

Comment: As the recursion is a tree structure, it depends on the tree level and how he calls the recursions. You can't just use a counter, you need the depth of the recursion (but unless we don't know his implementation, we can only guess).

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Yes. I'm agreeing with you but for a quick solution you can set numbers to a global variable in a recursive function. It's not counter but it can be used like a counter.

Comment: Sure, but then this is a duplicate question as I flagged above.

Comment: Yes this is a duplicate of the question you flagged